# Difficulty with classes in classes

Tags: c++, class

I have just started learning C++ so forgive me for a very noobish question.
I have no clue how to break down what my compiler is telling me. I just cannot see my mistake.

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Point{
public:
    Point(int x, int y);    
    ~Point();
    int getX() const {return itsX;}
    int getY() const {return itsY;}
    void setX(int i) {itsX=i;}
    void setY(int i) {itsY=i;}
private:
    int itsX;
    int itsY;
};

Point::Point(int x, int y) {
    itsX = x;
    itsY = y;
}

Point::~Point() { // deconstructor - doesn't do anything
}

class Rectangle {
public:
    Rectangle(int w, int h, Point sP);
    ~Rectangle();

    void setUpperLeft(Point p)  {itsUpperLeft = p;}
    void setUpperRight(Point p) {itsUpperRight = p;}
    void setLowerLeft(Point p)  {itsLowerLeft = p;}
    void setLowerRight(Point p) {itsLowerRight = p;}

    void getPoints();

private:
    Point itsUpperLeft;
    Point itsUpperRight;
    Point itsLowerLeft;
    Point itsLowerRight;

    int itsWidth;
    int itsHeight;
};

Rectangle::~Rectangle() { // deconstructor - doesn't do anything
}

Rectangle::Rectangle(int w, int h, Point sP) {
    itsWidth = w;
    itsHeight = h;

    setUpperLeft( sP );
    setUpperRight(Point point( sP.getX() + itsWidth, sP.getY ));
    setLowerLeft( Point point( sP.getX(), sP.getY() + itsHeight) );
    setLowerRight( Point point( sP.getX() + itsWidth, sP.getY() + itsHeight ));
}


void Rectangle::getPoints() {
    cout << "Coordinates of upper left angle are:  "<< "x=" << itsUpperLeft.getX() << "\t y=" << itsUpperLeft.getY() << endl;
    cout << "Coordinates of upper right angle are:   "<< "x=" << itsUpperRight.getX() << "\t y=" << itsUpperRight.getY() << endl;
    cout << "Coordinates of lower left angle are:  "<< "x=" << itsLowerLeft.getX() << "\t y=" << itsLowerLeft.getY() << endl;
    cout << "Coordinates of lower right angle are:  "<< "x=" << itsLowerRight.getX() << "\t y=" << itsLowerRight.getY() << endl;

    cout << "----------------------------------------------------------";
}*/

int main() {
        Rectangle rect(100, 20, Point po(100, 200) );
        rect.getPoints();
}
```

Sorry in advance if this wasted your time.

Comment: Always include the code in the question please.

Comment: How does this relate to C?

Comment: @user3211050 - why have you tagged this as C?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Unfortunately, your post does not fit the criteria for a "good" question on this site as it lacks detail as to the **specific problem** in your program. This is one of many characteristics a post can have that can qualify it for closure. Closure can be avoided or reversed by improving your post. Your question can be improved by adding more information about what problems you're experiencing, unexpected behavior, and including error messages. For more information on what makes a good question, read the [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First thing to notice is that your Point class cant be default constructed (it has no constructor which can be called without any parameters).

Second thing is that you initialize Rectangles' points in constructor body. What you might not know is that all members of object are already initialized when constructor body is reached. If you want to customize how those members are initialized you need to do this in initialization list. Since you are not doing it, compiler will try to default initialize those members for you... and since Point can't be default initialized you get compilation error.

Fixed Rectangle ctor:

```
Rectangle::Rectangle(int w,int h,Point sP)
: itsUpperLeft(sP), itsUpperRight(sP.getX() + w, sP.getY()),
  itsLowerLeft(sP.getX(),sP.getY()+ h), itsLowerRight(sP.getX() +w, sP.getY() + h),
  itsWidth(w), itsHeight(h)
  {}
```

Fixed main:

```
int main(){
  Rectangle rect(100,20, Point(100,200) );
  rect.getPoints();
}
```

Comment: Wow, thanks for a very fast response. I certainly wasn't aware of that! Thank you for clearing things up for me

Answer (score 0):

`setUpperRight(Point point( sP.getX()+itsWidth, sP.getY ));` is wrong. You want to pass a temporarely created `Point` to the function? Then write `setUpperRight(Point( sP.getX()+itsWidth, sP.getY ));`, that means only an explicit constructor call *without* variable name.

Answer (score 0):

When you call something such as:

```
setUpperRight(Point point( sP.getX()+itsWidth, sP.getY ));
```

You don't declare a name for the temporary variable you pass, you just say `Point`. Like this:

```
setUpperRight(Point( sP.getX()+itsWidth, sP.getY ));
```

And you need a default constructor if you plan on using it.